# ブラウザでHLSを再生方法

Tags: hls, browser

ブラウザでHLSを再生させたいと思っています。SafariではHLSを再生できますが、その他のブラウザでも再生させたいと思っています。
オープンソースでHLSが再生できるようです。
https://github.com/mangui/flashls
で、HLSが再生できるオープンソースが集めれていますが、以下の2つのケースが再生できません。
もしかすると試し方が悪いのかもしれませんが、再生可否とともにこのプレイヤーを使ったら再生できますという情報があれば教えていただけると助かります。

(1) ライブ再生
m3u8ファイルの中は以下のようになっています。

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:8064
#EXTINF:10,
24_576bd7d6.ts
#EXTINF:10,
24_576bd7e0.ts
#EXTINF:10,
24_576bd7ea.ts
```

(※#EXT-X-ENDLISTがありません)

(2) バイト指定のHLS再生
m3u8の中身は以下のようになっています。

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:20
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
##EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:10.01,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1835632@0
20160404_193000_16.ts
#EXTINF:10.01,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1901996@1835632
20160404_193000_16.ts
#EXTINF:10.01,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1777540@3737628
20160404_193000_16.ts
・・・・
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:259816@312737624
20160404_193000_16.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[MDNにサポート状況が整理](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video#HLS)されています。Firefox、Safari、Chrome、IE10+など多くの環境で再生できるようです。[デモサイト](http://rreverser.github.io/mpegts/)もありました。